# Van der Pol's identity for the sum of divisors and a quartic polynomial equation for odd perfect numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, inequalities, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

In [Touchard (1953)](https://oeis.org/A000385/a000385.pdf) it is mentioned that the sum of divisors $\sigma(n)$ satisfies the following recurrence relation ($n>1$):

$$n^2(n-1) = \frac{6}{\sigma(n)} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(3n^2-10k^2)\sigma(k)\sigma(n-k)$$

Substituting in this equation an odd perfect number $n = \sigma(n)/2$ we find that it is a root of the quartic polynomial:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= x^4-x^3+12a_0x^2-60a_1x+60a_2 \\
&= (x^3+(n-1)x^2+(12a_0+n^2-n)x+12a_0n+n^3-n^2-60a_1)(x-n)
\end{align}
$$

where

$$a_i = \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}k^i \sigma(k)\sigma(n-k),\text{ } i=0,1,2$$

However, computations with [Sagemath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtj8sOwiAQRfd8BelGBtoItHHhQj_EtAmxrSHVqUH0-x1an1FW9w7JOblt13PnBOYe1ozTC128BuSX60nsLv5wcmIAOQcsKA5Set6PgQ_cIw8OD50wOf0ZWFploAbGWoKex2NF2PiNjU1VxKZUxsrJqkHGxhYrPVdDVT2LfZPKf6RSTdYEUOINVEhATKAPCdK1LPBLxdjNBbGIC2BpD6Y9OysHZX73Ga2hnv3n4DESoHf7OAbx2gl51lNA2Gi-zfLHPVW4A8eyYlw=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) (it takes a few seconds to do the computation) seem to suggest, that for an odd number $m$, we have

$$f(m) > 0, \text{for } m>1 \text{ odd}$$

**Edit**: By comment of @JeroenNoels $f(945,945)<0$ so the last claim is wrong, but still in this case we have $f(n,t)$ is irreducible and $f(n,n)\neq 0$.

This observation would maybe prove, that there are no odd perfect numbers. I am aware that $\sigma(k)\sigma(n-k)$ is kind of like a black box to handle, but it would be nice, if maybe for some special cases where $m$ is odd the last inequality could be proven.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**:
It might be noticed that it seems like for $n>1$, odd the polynomial $f(x)$ is irreducible over the rational numbers.

Here are the first polynomials:

```
n, f(n,t), f(n,n)>0?
3 t^4 - t^3 + 36*t^2 - 180*t + 180 f(n,n)>0 ? True
5 t^4 - t^3 + 228*t^2 - 1860*t + 3300 f(n,n)>0 ? True
7 t^4 - t^3 + 696*t^2 - 7920*t + 20160 f(n,n)>0 ? True
9 t^4 - t^3 + 1548*t^2 - 22500*t + 72900 f(n,n)>0 ? True
11 t^4 - t^3 + 2940*t^2 - 51600*t + 204600 f(n,n)>0 ? True
13 t^4 - t^3 + 4956*t^2 - 102360*t + 478920 f(n,n)>0 ? True
15 t^4 - t^3 + 7752*t^2 - 185760*t + 1004400 f(n,n)>0 ? True
17 t^4 - t^3 + 11376*t^2 - 307620*t + 1900260 f(n,n)>0 ? True
19 t^4 - t^3 + 16020*t^2 - 481980*t + 3309420 f(n,n)>0 ? True
21 t^4 - t^3 + 22080*t^2 - 735120*t + 5559120 f(n,n)>0 ? True
```

Is there a irreducibility criterion which might be applied to **all** ($n=3,\ldots,21$) of these example polynomials?

**Third Edit ( and I hope the last :) )**:
The odd perfect number is also a root of the polynomial:

$$g(x) = x^4-x^3-9A_0x^2+30A_2$$

where

$$A_i = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^i \sigma(k)\sigma(n-k),i=0,2$$

But numerical computations suggest, that:

$$\gcd(f(x),g(x))=1$$

which would lead to a contradiction.

**Can this last claim about the $\gcd$ be proven?**

Comment: also asked on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3839696/van-der-pols-identity-for-the-sum-of-divisors-and-a-quartic-polynomial-equation

Comment: That looks very interesting! Thanks for sharing.
I did some numerical experiments and found f(n,n) to be negative for n = 945.
There could be some patterns here.
For example the arithmetic sequence n = 945 + 630 * k provides many more counterexamples (but not all).

Comment: @JeroenNoels: Thanks for your comment. Did you find a counterexample to $f(n,t)$ being irreducible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JeroenNoels: I checked your claim about $n=945$ and it seems to be true. At least it is not a zero of $f(n,t)$...

Comment: @JeroenNoels  Presumably 945 is a counterexample because it is abundant. In general any abundant number should be a counterexample I think?

Comment: @JoshuaZ: You mean a counterexample to $f(n,n)>0$ or do you mean a counterexample to $f(n,t)$ being irreducible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @stackExchangeUser f(n,n)>0.

Comment: Dear @JeoenNoels, Thank you for your suggestion. I have edited the question, but the change will appear after someone has approved it. Meanwhile, you maybe might want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3839696/van-der-pols-identity-for-the-sum-of-divisors-and-a-quartic-polynomial-equation

Comment: @JoshuaZ  All 38 odd abundant numbers listed in http://oeis.org/A005231 give a negative f(n,n).  I do not know if this generalizes though.

Comment: Using the Ramanujan Identity ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series#Ramanujan_identities ) it follows that every perfect number $n$ satisfies: $8n^4-2n^3-3 \sigma_3(n)n^2+24 A_2=0$.

Comment: related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372766/is-there-a-similar-formula-like-ramanunjans-eisenstein-series-identity-for-su

Comment: Showing that $\gcd(f_n(x),g_n(x))=1$ for all $n$ would disprove the existence of an odd perfect number, since such $n$ would be a zero of both $f_n(x)$ and $g_n(x)$, meaning that $\gcd(f_n(x),g_n(x))\ne 1$. So, are you asking to disprove the existence of an odd perfect number?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: No, of course not, since this is off-topic ;) But maybe with your identities we can replace the $a_i,A_i$ with some other untractable function such as $\sigma_3(n)$ etc. ?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question then here.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: You are right with your observation. But it would be nice if one can use your identities to express $f_n(x)$ and $g_n(x)$ in a different form. Maybe this is more tractable?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking, unfortunately.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I think that one can use your identities from the previous question, to replace $a_i$ and $A_i$ with $\sigma_3(n)$. This would lead to 2 polynomials $F_n(x)$ and $G_n(x)$ which hopefully have numerically $\gcd(F_n(x),G_n(x))=1$ and $F_n(n)=0, G_n(n)=0$ for the odd perfect number $n$. I think this would be helpful to have.

Comment: $\gcd(F_n(x),G_n(x))=1$ together with $F_n(n)=G_n(n)=0$ is not possible, since $F_n(n)=G_n(n)=0$ implies that $x-n$ divides $\gcd(F_n(x),G_n(x))$.

Comment: Dear @MaxAlekseyev: My question is, if your replace $a_i$ and $A_i$ in the question with your identities, then what are the polynomials $F_n(x)$ and $G_n(x)$ which the odd perfect number is a root of? ( Then one can evaluate those polynomials at odd numbers $m$ and see if they have $\gcd=1$. If this is the case, one would have an attack on the OPN problem). Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: @stackExchangeUser: I do not see how these polynomials can help for the OPN problem. To evaluate the polynomials for a given $n$, one should be able to compute $\sigma_3(n)$, and thus be able to compute $\sigma(n)$ and test the quality $\sigma(n)=2n$ directly.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: Using your technique with the linear dependence it seems it is not possible to derive formulas for $a_i$. Hence to evaluate $f_n(x)$ it seems there is not a simple formula since it has coefficients $a_i$ not $A_i$. But I have tested that $f_n(x)$ is irreducible for a lot of odd $n$s, which contradicts $f_n(n)=0$ for an odd perfect number. Thus it still is an attack on OPN.

Comment: @stackExchangeUser: First, $f_n(x)$ being irreducible for some $n$ does not contradict the existence of an OPN. Second, it's not an attack on OPN, but just an obscure way to test the perfectness of $n$; and it does not  have any benefits over the direct testing of the equality $\sigma(n)=2n$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: You are right, it is a way of testing perfectness for an odd number.